# Unable to get session data from paypal express checkout in laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4, paypal

I am unable to get session information in omnipay laravel 4 after getting express checkout return after making express checkout.

I do get Tokens and PayerID noting else. Session data of that site become empty.

Please tell how can I completePurchase Process. Is there any way to get purchase order ID from paypal. I am using omnipay.

```
public function doSaveAndProcessedToPayPal( $purchaseOrder)
    {

        $purchaseOrderId =  $purchaseOrder->id;

        Session::put('currentUserEmail', $email);
        Session::put('purchaseOrderId', $purchaseOrderId);
        Session::put('amount', $amount);


        $gateway = $this->getPayPalGateway();

        $items = new Omnipay\Common\ItemBag();

        $items->add(array(
            'name' => $productName,
            'quantity' => '1',
            'price' => (float)$amount,
        ));

        $response = $gateway->purchase(
            array(
                'cancelUrl' => CANCEL_URL,
                'returnUrl' => RETURN_URL,
                'amount' =>  (float)$amount,
                'currency' => $currency
            )
        )->setItems($items)->send();

        $response->redirect();
    }

    public function doPerformPostPaymentOperation()
    {


        $gateway = $this->getPayPalGateway();

        $purchaseOrderId = Session::get('purchaseOrderId');
        $amount = Session::get('amount');
        $currency = Session::get('currency');

        $data = Session::all();
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r( $data );
        echo "</pre>";
        echo $purchaseOrderId;
        die();

        $response = $gateway->completePurchase(array(
            'transactionId' => "ORD-".$purchaseOrderId,
            'transactionReference' => "REF-".$purchaseOrderId,
            'amount' => (float)$amount,
            'currency' => $currency,
        ))->send();

        if ( ! $response->isSuccessful())
        {
            throw new Exception($response->getMessage());
        }
    }


Output
Array
(
    [_token] => lnvG1S3eU2JsHJSciOTjixEEHiSwZVX47daRLDXE
    [flash] => Array
        (
            [old] => Array
                (
                )

            [new] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
```